# send email to multiple recipients using net/smtp

Tags: ruby, email

I have this code:

```
require "net/smtp"

MAIL_SERVER = "xxx.ad.xxx.net"

def lib_sending_report(email_hash)

    # define message body

    message = <<"MESSAGE_END"

From: <#{email_hash[:sender]}>

To: <#{email_hash[:recipients]}>

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-type: text/html

Subject: #{email_hash[:subject]}

<p>Hi All,</p>

    <p>We've just executed a round of load test.</p>

<p>Regards</p>
MESSAGE_END

    Net::SMTP.start(MAIL_SERVER) do |smtp|
      smtp.send_message message, email_hash[:sender], email_hash[:recipients]
    end
end

test = ""
lib_sending_report( {:sender => "abc@xxx.com",
                      :recipients => "abc@xxxx.com",
                      :subject => "Load.Test.Report.of.#{test}"} )
```

When I change `:recipients => "abc@xxxx.com"` to `:recipients => "abc@xxxx.com;efg@xxx.com"`, it gives me this error:

```
 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)
```

I can successfully send email when `:recipients => "abc@xxxx.com"` just have one recipient.

Where am I wrong? It seems that the separator(semicolon) I used is wrong.

I tried to use comma instead of semicolon, but it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Net::SMTP's `send_message` takes an array of "To:" address strings.

Per the documentation:

> to_addr is a String or Strings or Array of Strings, representing the destination mail address or addresses.

This example from the documentation shows how:

```
Net::SMTP.start('smtp.example.com') do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message msgstr,
                    'from@example.com',
                    ['dest@example.com', 'dest2@example.com']
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works~ I concentrate more on the semicolon and forget the `To` parameter of `send_message`